# Upload files from webserver to GitHub

Tags: ubuntu, github

I was wondering if it is possible to, via git, copy files from my webserver to my GitHub repo to start editing it with github?

Thanks

Comment: Of course! Just create a git repo and push. Nothing else to it.

Comment: @jhpratt so I have a folder on my server called test in /var/www, I also have a test.git folder in /var/repo. Inside the test.git folder I executed the git init --base command, now where do I go from there?

Comment: Have you looked at any guides online? This would answer all of your questions for basic git usage.

Comment: I have but most of them are for the reverse procedure, i.e. committing changes from github

Comment: [This](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-using-the-command-line/) is literally the first result for "copy files from server to github" ─ not sure what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to copy the files directly from your webserver to GitHub, then no, that is not possible with git alone. While you could do it with some fairly straightforward shell scripting, I recommend that you try it manually for now.

First, create a new repository on GitHub - the following documentation will walk you through this: https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/.

Then you can clone it to your computer! - https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Download a copy of your current webserver files - your html, css, js (if any), images, etc, the whole shebang, but make sure you don't have any passwords or other secrets in there.

Copy your webserver files into the folder that was created when you cloned the repository.

Now, you need to add your files to the "index" (also called the staging area or cache), and then commit them to the repository. To do this, open a terminal, `cd` to the cloned repository folder, and then run:

```
git commit -am 'Initial Commit'
```

Lastly, push your changes to GitHub:

```
git push
```

### Done! (but read below...)

I suggest having a look at GitHub Pages https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/.
If you used GitHub Pages, each time you `git push` your new changes to GitHub, the website will update automatically. Whereas if you follow my answer above, you will need to reupload your website to your webserver each time you want it to update.

**A note about editing files on GitHub:**

While GitHub has a great text editor inbuilt into their web interface, I only use it for simple changes - to correct spelling mistakes, grammar, etc. When you want to make changes to HTML, CSS, or code in general, it is best to use a text editor designed for coding (like [Atom](https://atom.io/)) on your computer, and then push the changes to GitHub with `git push`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could I also use sublime text editor, if so how could I link it to my github account to edit repo's?

Comment: @harrycameron you need to Google for a git plugin for sublime text.